# Is there an intuitive way of visualising vector derivatives?

Tags: calculus

Say we are looking for $\frac{\delta x}{\delta \vec{y}}$ where $\vec{y}$ is a vector. $\frac{\delta x}{\delta \vec{y}}$ is the derivative of $x$ wrt a vector $\vec{y}$.  If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then I suppose we can say where $\frac{\delta x}{\delta \vec{y}} = 0$ we have the point in that space where x is maximised/minimised. However, what happens if x is a vector? What is the intuitive meaning then?

Comment: could you give your definition of $\frac{\delta x}{\delta \vec{y}}$ ?

Comment: [There is an entire wiki page dedicated to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, when you say $\frac{dx}{dy}$, $x$ is some function (whose value changes according to where you look at it on its domain), yes? Therefore, the derivative of $x$ with respect to $y$ tells you the rate-of-change of $x$ in the direction of $y$ ($y$, as you said, is a vector). That is, if you were to look at the domain of $x$ along the vector $y$, you get the rate of change of $x$ with respect to $y$. (So when that derivative reaches 0, we have a maximum *or* a minimum rate-of-change of $x$ in the direction of $y$.)

Now, note I'm using the term "rate-of-change" pretty often. If $x$ is a function, whose value changes according to where you are on its domain, then $x$ clearly has *some* rate of change.

But, if $x$ is a *vector*, then... is it changing at all? (Think about it before you read further!)

> Nope! The derivative of a vector is always $0$—because vectors don't change. It's just a static object. So the derivative of a  vector is $0$ with respect to *anything*, including other vectors.